# AudioFile trimming not working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avasset

in my app i am trim the audio file.

but its not working every-time its showing me failed

this is my code

```
 @IBAction func trimAudioPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    isTrim = true

    let audioFileInput = filepath

    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy_MMM_dd_HH_mm_ss"
    let strdate = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

    print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("fileURL"))

    let extensionofFile = filepath.pathExtension!

    let strOutputFilePath123 : String = String(filepath.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!)

    strOutputFilePath = "\(strOutputFilePath123)\(strdate).\(extensionofFile)"

    let fileManger = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManger.fileExistsAtPath(strOutputFilePath) {
        do {
            (try fileManger.removeItemAtPath(strOutputFilePath))
        }
        catch let error { print(error)
        }
    }

    let audioFileOutput : NSURL = NSURL(string: strOutputFilePath)!

    let asset = AVAsset(URL: audioFileInput)

    let succcess = self.exportAsset(asset, toFilePath: strOutputFilePath)
    print(succcess)

    self.dismissView()

}



func exportAsset(avAsset: AVAsset, toFilePath filePath: String) -> Bool {
    var tracks = avAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    if tracks.count == 0 {
        return false
    }
    let track = tracks[0]

    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)

    let supportedTypeArray = exportSession!.supportedFileTypes
    for str: String in supportedTypeArray {

        if nil == exportSession {
            return false
        }
    }
    print(leftV)
    print(rightV)
    let startTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(leftV), 1)
    let stopTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(rightV), 1)

    let exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)
    let exportAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()

     let exportAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: track)

    exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [exportAudioMixInputParameters]
    exportSession!.outputURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)

    exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A

    exportSession!.timeRange = exportTimeRange

    exportSession!.audioMix = exportAudioMix

    exportSession!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({() -> Void in
        if .Completed == exportSession!.status {
            print("Success")

        }
        else if .Failed == exportSession!.status {
            print("Failed")
            print("Export Session Status: \(exportSession!.status)")

        }
        else {

            print("Export Session Status: \(exportSession!.status)")
        }

    })
    return true
}
```

i dont know where its going wrong

here is my string inputfile path

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/07166600-AAEA-436F-BE6B-93839C180F19/Documents/Default/recording-2016-08-31-18-28-12.m4a
```

here is my output file path

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/07166600-AAEA-436F-BE6B-93839C180F19/Documents/Default/2016_Aug_31_18_38_31.m4a
```

or even starttime and stop time is also perfect. so how can i solve this. and let me knonw if there is any other approch.

this is the error which i got

```
export failed Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3000 "Cannot create file" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create file, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc9415142b0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12115 "(null)"}})
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: no error buddy its just going in this loop .Failed == exportSession!.status

Comment: What is the status?

Comment: you have to remove url in export session. Try this.

Comment: what are `leftv` and `rightv`?

Comment: its 0 and 5 @RhythmicFistman

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
exportSession!.outputURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
```

is wrong. `filePath` is not a path; it is already a `file://` URL.

The quick fix is to change the `outputURL` to this:

```
exportSession!.outputURL = NSURL(string: filePath)!
```

There's confusion between file paths and file URLs in this code. e.g. `filepath` is a file `NSURL`, but `strOutputFilePath123` is a `String` that contains a `file://` scheme URI.

To convert a file `NSURL` to a `String` path, you should use `url.path`.